# How to make the parent widget transparent while a child is opaque

Tags: flutter, dart, transparency

Let's assume the following code, I want to make the container transparent but not the text widget inside of it. Unfortunately, the transparency applied to the child too.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: const Color(0x00000000),
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Hello, World!',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue), // Child text is opaque
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How about using Stack

Comment: It does not. Child text is visible. Do you want it to invisible as well?

Answer (score 0):

To make the container transparent while keeping the text opaque, you can use the `Opacity` widget to wrap the text widget instead of applying the transparency to the container.

Here is an example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: const Center(
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: 1.0, // set the opacity to 1.0 to keep the child widget fully opaque
              child: Text(
                'Hello, World!',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

By wrapping the `Text` widget with the `Opacity` widget and setting its opacity to 1.0, you ensure that the text remains fully opaque while the container is transparent.